# google.maps.MarkerShape not loaded

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to create a MarkerShape object with google maps api (the last version, 3.9.2). Unfortunately, it seems that MarkerShape api is not loaded: here is what firebug's console shows me:

> >>> google.maps.version
>
> "3.9.2"
>
> >>> google.maps.MarkerShape
>
> undefined

Am I doing something wrong ? The last version of gmaps documentation for MarkerShape is here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerShape

Thx

Edit: here is an example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vszHk/6/ or just go to an official example like here https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple and open firebug

Comment: Here is an example on jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/vszHk/6/

Comment: or just go to an official example like here https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple and open firebug

Comment: I must be missing something, on the jsfiddle I only see three alert statements.  Never mind trying to do alerts, show us the actual code of you trying to use the MarkerShape class properly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your problem is you are trying to treat google.maps.MarkerShape as a constructor. It's just an object, not a constructor.

So doing something like the following **is wrong** as there isn't a MarkerShape method in the google.maps object:

```
var marker_shape = new google.maps.MarkerShape();
```

To create a MarkerShape you can just create an object literal:

```
var marker_shape = {coords: [0,0,50,50], type: "rect"}
```

Then you can add this to the object literal you pass to the google.maps.Marker constructor. Eg.

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: lat_lng_object,
    map: map,
    shape: marker_shape
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that 3.9.2 is the latest Nightly version, have you tried referring to an older more stable version, e.g. 3.9.1 or 3.8 (last Release version)

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning

e.g. http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.8&sensor=false

Comment: Tried with 3.8 but does not seem to work... I'm sure that I'm doing something wrong (jsfiddle for 3.8: http://jsfiddle.net/vszHk/7/)